# Calculations for Data Rates, CPU Utilization and suitability of a specific MCU for parallel TX and RX operations

Tags: microcontroller

I am currently working on a project involving the STM32F722 microcontroller, and I'm seeking guidance on calculating the maximum data rate, total data rate, and CPU utilization rate for specific operations performed in parallel. The main goal is to understand if a given MCU is suitable for my application.

Here are the operations I'm interested in:

**Transmit and Receive Data:**

*Operation:* Transmitting and receiving data at a rate of 160 Mbps via GPIO

*Question:* How can I calculate the maximum data rate and total data rate for this operation on the STM32F722?

**Modulate, Encode, Demodulate, and Decode Data:**

*Operation*: Modulating, encoding, demodulating, and decoding data.

*Question:* What calculations should be considered to determine the maximum data rate and CPU utilization rate for these operations performed in parallel on the STM32F722?

**Monitoring the Transmitter and Receiver:**

*Operation:* Monitoring the transmitter and receiver via I2C.

*Question:* Are there specific considerations or formulas to calculate the CPU utilization rate when monitoring the transmitter and receiver simultaneously?

I have conducted order of magnitude estimations for parallel transmission and reception, but I would appreciate clarification on their correctness. Specifically, I used the following formulas:

> **Data Rate = MCU Clock Frequency / (Number of Data Bits * Number of TX or RX bits)**

> **Utilization = Required Data Rate / (MCU Clock Frequency / Number of TX or RX bits)**

- MCU Clock Frequency: Assuming a clock speed of 217 MHz
- Number of Data Bits: Assuming 8 bits
- Number of TX or RX Bits: Assuming 1 for simplicity
- Required Data Rate : 160 Mbps

> **Data Rate = 217 MHz/ (8 bits × 1) ​≈ 27.125 Mbps**

> ​**Utilization = 160 Mbps/(217MHz/1) ≈ 0.07372 %**

Additionally, if there are any crucial specifications or factors that I may have overlooked. I would greatly appreciate your insights and suggestions. Could you provide some valuable resources?

Comment: At those kind of speeds, a generic Cortex M is unsuitable. You should be looking at high end MCUs or maybe DSPs.

Comment: FYI, The fastest data rate in the I2C specification is 3.4 Mbps (high speed mode).

Comment: It is unknown what your data is, how you plan to transmit and receive it, and you don't tell where you got or invented those numbers and formulas - so nobody can say if they are correct.

Comment: I’d suggest that supporting a 160Mbps protocol will require significantly more than 0.07% cpu utilization methinks. You can’t draw a simple relationship between cpu clock rate and mbps of data - the memory may take a number of clocks per operation, instruction fetches may take a number of clocks, the number of instructions to send/receive the data can vary widely.  Even with a lot of experience, determining suitability will usually entail building a proof of concept where real measurements can be taken. Only then do you have a benchmark.

Comment: This is something you learn by carefully studying the datasheet to understand how the IO works.  If you've picked well and your device has SRAM buffers with high speed DMA for IO, it is possible you may be able to receive data at that rate with very little CPU.  Note however that actually processing that data after you receive it may be much more intensive.

Comment: This sounds like a FPGA project to me.